# Problem with CompareTo

Tags: c#, comparison, compare, compareto

I am trying to implement a sorted list. I have created the class I want to have stored in the list, but for some reason when I try and run the sort the sort method I get an exception thrown. It appears something behind the scenes is passing in a `null` reference into the `CompareTo` method I have implemented.

Here’s what I believe to be relevant code.

Data object is defined like this:

```
namespace PrioritisedRequestQueue
{
public class XactTask : IComparable<XactTask>
{
    public int priority;
    public DateTime submitted;
    public string name;

    public XactTask( int priority, DateTime submitted, string name)
    {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.submitted = submitted;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int CompareTo(XactTask rhs )
    {
        //EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE AFTER A NULL RHS HAS BEEN PASSED IN**
        Console.WriteLine("comparing " + rhs.priority+"to "+this.priority); 

        if (rhs.priority <= this.priority)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entered first if");
            Console.WriteLine("comparing " + rhs.submitted + "to " + 
                this.submitted);
            if (rhs.submitted <= this.submitted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entered second if");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In else");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the class to hold the list is defined like this:

```
namespace PrioritisedRequestQueue
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public List<XactTask> tasks;

        public Class1()
        {
            tasks = new List<XactTask>();
        }

        public void sort()
        {
            tasks.Sort();
        }

        public void add(XactTask task)
        {
            tasks.Add(task);

        }

    }
}
```

Here is the program I use to do the testing:

```
PrioritisedRequestQueue.Class1 tester = new PrioritisedRequestQueue.Class1();

tester.add(new PrioritisedRequestQueue.XactTask(1, DateTime.Now, "test1"));
tester.add(new PrioritisedRequestQueue.XactTask(1, DateTime.Now, "test2"));
Console.WriteLine(tester.tasks[0].name);
Console.WriteLine(tester.tasks[1].name);
tester.tasks.Sort();
```

The output of the test program is:

```
 comparing 1to 1 Entered first if
 comparing 16/05/2011 14:41:57to 16/05/2011 14:41:57 
 Entered second if
 comparing 1to 1 Entered first if
 comparing 16/05/2011 14:41:57to 16/05/2011 14:41:57 
 Entered second if
 comparing 1to 1 
 Entered first if
 comparing 16/05/2011 14:41:57to 16/05/2011 14:41:57 
 Entered second if
 comparing 1to 1 
 Entered first if
 comparing 16/05/2011 14:41:57to 16/05/2011 14:41:57 
 Entered second if
```

Then it seems to pass a `null` rhs object into the compare method and I get a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to access the priority of rhs.

Can you tell me why this is happening and what I have to do to address this?

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: @Uwe His question gives all the information requried, in a relatively concise and well formatted way. I don't think anything should be cut out, as it all looks relevant.

Comment: Are you sure it's a null ref exception?  I could see a different exception being thrown

Comment: @user Please can you highlight exactly where the Exception occurs. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: @Uwe, if you did read the first paragraph you would see it states the problem Im having. The rest of the information is then provided to aid anyone that thinks they might be able to help. In my opinion it is far worse to have not enough information that too much.

Comment: @RB If I do see horizontal scrollbars in source code fragments, my mind seems to just turn itself off :-).

Comment: @RB Thanks alot, it's much easier to read now :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I run your code, I get an `InvalidOperationException` because `CompareTo` is not implemented correctly.

Your `CompareTo` implementation *must* return `0` if `rhs` is the same as `this` (i.e., this object and the object being compared are equal). It also should not fail if `rhs == null`, but should order `null` in a consistent way; this is typically done by always returning `1` to sort `null` before all valid objects.

The [documentation for IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx) lists the following rules, which must be followed in order for Sort to function correctly:

- `A.CompareTo(A)` is required to return
  zero.
- If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns zero, then
  `B.CompareTo(A)` is required to return
  zero.
- If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns zero and
  `B.CompareTo(C)` returns zero, then
  `A.CompareTo(C)` is required to return
  zero.
- If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns a value
  other than zero, then `B.CompareTo(A)`
  is required to return a value of the
  opposite sign.
- If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns a value x
  that is not equal to zero, and
  `B.CompareTo(C)` returns a value y of
  the same sign as x, then
  `A.CompareTo(C)` is required to return
  a value of the same sign as x and y.

To fix the problem, ensure that your implementation of `CompareTo` returns 0 when `priority == rhs.priority && submitted == rhs.submitted`.